# Update React Component With Updated Data From Firestore

Tags: reactjs, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a chrome extension that stores data in Firestore and populates that data to the frontend. I always have to refresh the page to see newly added data, which isn’t a user friendly experience. How can I update the UI to show the newly updated data without having to refresh the page?

So far, I've tried using useEffect to get the data. Inside of it, I'm using a function that gets data from Firestore cached inside of chrome local storage.

Here is my code

```
const getFolderData = () => {
     getDataFromChrome("docId").then((res: any) => {
         setDocId(res.docId);
      });

    getDataFromChrome("content").then((res: any) => {
      //console.log("getting in mainfolder",res);
      // for (const item of res.content) {
      //   if (item.type.toLowerCase() === "subfolder") {
      //     // console.log(item)
      //     getSubFolder(item.id);
      //   }
      // }
      for (const item of res.content) {
        setTiersContent((pre: any) => [...pre, item]);
      }
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    getFolderData();


  }, []);
```

I also get this error. I'm also using the chrome extension API to communicate with a background script. It could be related to the problem

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: A listener indicated an asynchronous response by returning true, but the message channel closed before a response was received
```

Answer (score -1):

I've never used firebase so I'm not sure what your functions do, I can only guess. A few things wrong from what I can see:

Your useEffect is set to only run on page load since the dep array is empty, I assume you want to refetch on some condition.

If any of the 2 functions is supposed to be a subscription, your useEffect needs to return a cancel function.

Refetch data when needed is not a new problem, packages like React Query has tools that optimize your requests and refetch when needed. I suggest you give it a shot if your app has more than 2-3 fetch requests.